# How to use fixed array in arrayformula?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I have a table like:

```
| 1 | 10 | <unique appearences from A&B>
| 2 | 10 | <unique appearences from A&B>
| 1 | 20 | <unique appearences from A&B>
| ... |
```

I want to use a fixed area (columns `A:B`) and count how much this combination of `A` & `B` appeared before including current row.
I use this formula: `=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A2:A<>"";COUNTIFS(A$2:A;A2:A;B$2:B;B2:B);""))`.
Each row with its own formula is working: *(for row A)*: `=COUNTIFS(A$2:A2;A2;B$2:B2;B2)`.

[Here my example sheet.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13nrWny5wWmAUkqrOKINAwnn7kgl-uOpmdmgpMFJAWd8/edit#gid=0)

Is it possible to make an area in an array formula as fixed?
For specific fields does `INDIRECT()` sometimes help but not for arrays.
`$` doesn't help either.
I mean I figured already out that some functions don't work with array formula like `JOIN()` - is this also such a case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(COUNTIFS(A2:A21&B2:B21,A2:A21&B2:B21,ROW(A2:A21),"<="&ROW(A2:A21)))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: this formula solves this solution I understand what you did here - but this doesn't actually answer my real question: how to say the formula to not change the array region?

Comment: what about `=AVERAGEIFS($D$2:$D;$A$2:$A;A2;$B$2:$B;B2)`? or should I ask another question?